# Deploying war on app server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven

Are there any limitations on what a WAR archive can contain when deploying to a full java ee 6 application server? Can i use the whole Java EE 6 API? If not how would I do it when i am using maven and that produces a WAR? Do you get maven to build several different artifacts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This guide defines which component in a Java EE application can contain what: http://java.sun.com/blueprints/guidelines/designing_enterprise_applications_2e (for the war see chapter 4 "Web Tier")

**Edit to add:**

With maven, in the pom.xml you can define the type of module should be built with the  `<packaging>...</packaging>` tag. Values are (amongst other) `jar`, `ejb` or `war` (see the [Maven POM documentation](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates))